# How to add an SVG pattern in d3 latest version

Tags: svg, d3.js, design-patterns, append, version

I have gone through the pattern example and tried that example in the latest d3 version. It shows me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'append')
>
> at index.html:61:9

Can you please tell me how to add an SVG pattern in the latest d3 version?

I tried the given example and I want the same behavior of pattern, but then in the latest d3 version.

Code:

```
// SVG injection: 
var svg = d3.select("#hook").append("svg").attr("id", "d3svg") 
            .attr("width", 120) 
            .attr("height", 120); 
//Pattern injection 
var defs = svg.append("defs") 
var pattern = defs.append("pattern") 
              .attr({ id:"hash4_4", width:"8", height:"8", patternUnits:"userSpaceOnUse", patternTransform:"rotate(-45)"}) 
              .append("rect") 
              .attr({ width:"4", height:"8", transform:"translate(0,0)", fill:"#88AAEE" }); 
//Shape design 
svg.append("g").attr("id","shape") 
               .append("circle") 
               .attr({cx:"60",cy:"60",r:"50", fill:"url(#hash4_4)" })
```

Comment: Please provide the example code.

Comment: // SVG injection:
var svg = d3.select("#hook").append("svg").attr("id", "d3svg")
    .attr("width", 120)
    .attr("height", 120);
//Pattern injection
var defs = svg.append("defs")
var pattern = defs.append("pattern")
  .attr({ id:"hash4_4", width:"8", height:"8", patternUnits:"userSpaceOnUse", patternTransform:"rotate(-45)"})
 .append("rect")
  .attr({ width:"4", height:"8", transform:"translate(0,0)", fill:"#88AAEE" });

//Shape design
svg.append("g").attr("id","shape")
    .append("circle")
.attr({cx:"60",cy:"60",r:"50", fill:"url(#hash4_4)" })

Comment: Can you please edit the question, add the code from the comment and make clear, which part of the example code belongs to which part of the question?